# Which Java Development Kit for Android development in IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I want to develop an Android application using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate and not Android Studio (since the Android development functionalities are the same, and Idea Ultimate offers me more flexibility for other tasks).
I installed the latest Android SDK but when configuring it on ItelliJ Idea it seems to not support the last JDK (v11).
I have read that Android studio ships with its own JDK (an OpenJDK distribution).
Which is the latest Oracle JDK I can use with Android SDK? Or, how do I get and which version should i get of OpenJDK, which can work with intelliJ Idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very highly recommend using AndroidStudio, first and foremost.

I'm unsure of many reasons *not* to use AndroidStudio for Android Development.
The only reasons I could think of would be if you need to use Xamarin or Unity or something like that.
Do you mind me asking, out of curiosity, what specific features you would be missing vs iJ?

Anyhow, to answer your question:
JDK7-JDK8.. Pretty sure JDK8 is what would currently be supported, if not mistaken.

Does this help?

Comment: Do you know which version of openJDK?